# \n newline character is ignored by java

Tags: java

I'm writing to a txt file and I'm appending \n (newline character). the character is shown clearly in System.out.println. but this character is not shown in the textfile. therefore, the textfile is composed by only one long line

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What operating system are you using? If you're using Windows, try "\r\n" - or (more universally), `System.getProperty("line.separator")`